Connecting to outside SQL Server node from Spark SQL running on Kubernetes
I have a Spark SQL application which is using a jdbc connection to connect to SQL server and read a table from data frame. The job was simply running on a local machine using Spark Connect.
At the moment, I am trying to move everything to kuberent, I have installed the kubernetes on the local drive machine.
However, when I run the Spark connect sever on kuberentes cluster, it cant connect to SQL server. The is probably due dockerization of Spark driver and executors on kubernetes.
Running below:
root@master-node:~# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://172.22.0.80:6443
CoreDNS is running at https://172.22.0.80:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'

I can successfully run Spark connect using a command like below:
./spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.1,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0 --conf spark.ui.port=4041 --driver-memory 8g --master k8s://https://172.22.0.80:6443  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=apache/spark-py

runnning a simple python appliaction to connect to above server can not read data from SQL server
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, col, lit, to_timestamp, substring, regexp_replace, cast
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.remote("sc://localhost").getOrCreate()

sql_db_ip = "172.22.0.60"
sql_db_port = "53817"
sql_db_user = "reports"
sql_db_password = "****"
...
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{}:{};databaseName={};integratedSecurity=false;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;user={};password={};".format(
sql_db_ip, sql_db_port, "test", sql_db_user, sql_db_password)
stg_count = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
            .option('dbtable', input_table_name) \
            .options(url=url, **properties) \
            .load()
stg_count.Count() # can't connect to sql server node when running on kubernetes, giving error here

I appreciate for any help or clue.
